# Is it possible ot inject an existing instance into the SeContainer instead of reflection

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee

In the following code:

```
import jakarta.enterprise.inject.se.SeContainer;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import jakarta.persistence.Persistence;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import jakarta.enterprise.inject.se.SeContainerInitializer;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class OrderRepositoryTest {
    private static EntityManager entityManager;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void init() {
        Map<String, String> configOverrides = new HashMap<>();
        configOverrides.put("jakarta.persistence.validation.mode", "none");
        EntityManagerFactory emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("primary-test", configOverrides);
        entityManager = emFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        SeContainerInitializer init = SeContainerInitializer.newInstance();
        init.addBeanClasses(OrderRepository.class);
        SeContainer c = init.initialize();
        OrderRepository sut = c.select(OrderRepository.class).get();
    }

}
```

the prepared static `EntityManager` instance is planned to be the dependency of `OrderRepository`, meaning the `OrderRepository` has an `@Inject private EntityManager` field. Obviously at this moment the `EntityManager` instance is not injected into the `SeContainer` yet and, the running of this code cause error:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type EntityManager with qualifiers @Default
```

**Question: is it possible to inject this prepared `EntityManager` instance into the `SeContainer` without using the `select` method? If so how?**